# Admob not showing banners, not even test ads, "ad request successful but no ad returned due to lack of ad inventory".

Tags: android, lua, admob, coronasdk, ads

When I try to run my program on my android device, the admob response is this: "ad request successful but no ad returned due to lack of ad inventory".

However, when I try to run my program with ads.show( "banner", { x=10000, y=10000, appId= appID, testMode=true} )
(the bool being there for displaying a test ad) It returns the same thing... any ideas why I dont get the test banners?

the app is in landscape mode, and the app is not yet released on the google play store.
here are the settings from my admob portal:(ALBUM) https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ju8Bl.png

Thanks for any help in advance! :)

Comment: It can be at that particular time, there is no ad available to show. It is recommended to use test ads to see if your app is displaying ads while testing. As they are not concerned with lack of inventory and also you can click test ads to check users can go through the app fluidly.

Comment: Hey! Thanks for the reply, but please read the question before you comment next time! :)

Comment: Are you creating program using Unity or ADT?

Answer (score 0):

Well, every documentation contains way to get test ads. So, I thought it must be there. 
For ADT, you can find it here:- developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/docs/admob/android/… Just find in page for "test ads".
Or just include the code as -

```
    // Create an ad request. Check logcat output for the hashed device ID to
        // get test ads on a physical device. e.g.
        // "Use AdRequest.Builder.addTestDevice("ABCDEF012345") to get test ads on this device."
        AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder()
                .addTestDevice(AdRequest.DEVICE_ID_EMULATOR)
                .build();
```

For Unity official plugin, it is here- github.com/googleads/googleads-mobile-plugins Click on Plugin to see instructions or direct link - https://github.com/googleads/googleads-mobile-plugins/tree/master/unity#test-ads

```
AdRequest request = new AdRequest.Builder()
.AddTestDevice(AdRequest.TestDeviceSimulator)       // Simulator.
.AddTestDevice("0123456789ABCDEF0123456789ABCDEF")  // Test Device 1.
.Build();
```

Not same you can see, library functions have difference of starting letter.